# Guardar 2 datos al tiempo en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 input con el mismo name, para registrar 2 nombres al tiempo

```
<form>
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="name_product" class="form-control" rows="2" name="name_product">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="name_product" class="form-control" rows="2" name="name_product">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Agregar Producto</button>
<form>
```

tengo este insert que me guarda en la tabla detail_courir_tmp

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `detail_addcourier_tmp` (`id`, `id_add`, `name_product`) VALUES (NULL, '".$numbers."','$name_product', NOW(), '".$user->username."');";
```

al darle en guardar solo ingresa el ultimo input, entonces como seria para ingresarlos los 2 al tiempo? con el mismo id_add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El id debe ser unico, si es posible omitirlo omitelo, pero el que te afecta es el atributo `name`, si quieres recibir varios deberas mandar un array, para ello debes mandarlo como

```
<input type="text" name="name_product[]"/>
```

Para tu query. Primero debes ajustar la cantidad de columnas, ya que solicitas ingresar datos solo en 3 columnas y llenas 5.

Debes correr el query por cada elemento que recibas del Form de esta forma

```
foreach ($_POST['name_product'] as $name_product) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO `detail_addcourier_tmp` (`id`, `id_add`, `name_product`) VALUES (NULL, '$numbers', '$name_product', NOW(), '$user->username');";
    mysqli_query($query)
}
```

Comment: no quiero recibir, quiero enviar, repecto al id me refiero a otro campo con un identificador distinto, es decir esta el id autoincrementable que no se repite y el id_add que seria el que tendria el mismo id para luego id_add agregarselo a un usuario para saber que esa info pertenece a dicho usuario

Comment: Lo que te comento es para enviar y posteriormente recibir, lo que mencionas no lo incluyes en el código de tu pregunta.

Comment: ya la reestructure

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada

Comment: Osea que para agregar otros campos digamos el apellido tengo que hacer otra consulta?